# IE 11 Caches get request even if request URL differs

Tags: internet-explorer, get, internet-explorer-11, cache-control

At first our application made a POST, which IE 11 does not cache. So everything worked fine. But due to **CORS** we switched to GET to make our life easier. Now we ran into a known issue, where IE caches the GET request.
Our Get Request looks like this:

`url/?action=myaction&data=base64codedData`

To prevent the **cache problem** we added the timestamp into the base64 encoded string on each GET request to ensure, that each GET request is different. But after the first request, we are still running into the **cache problem**.

To solve this, we added the headers **Cache-control** and **Pragma**.

**Just to be curious:**
Why does IE caches a GET request which is obviously different from the previous ones?

Answer (score 0):

IE is very eager to cache pages and [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/234067/how-to-prevent-caching-in-internet-explorer) explains the effort you need to make to prevent caching.

Each browser has different default behavior for caching and it is designed like this. You could also refer to [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2010/07/14/caching-improvements-in-internet-explorer-9/) for more information about caching mechanism of IE: *We’ve made a tremendous number of improvements to the way that Internet Explorer 9 caches content to ensure that as many resources as possible are loaded from the cache.*